# VB.NET InstanceContext not working

Tags: vb.net, web-services

Thanks for all the help over the years - I've never had an issue requiring a post as most things are already answered!  Unforunately, I finally have one...

Consuming a web service which requires a very specifically phrased token in the SOAP header as follows:

```
<soapenv:header>
<Authentication xmlns="...">12345</Authentication>
</soapenv:header>
```

To achieve this, I am trying to use the (New InstanceContext(Me)) declaration on my proxy but VB 2010 Express does not allow it and nowhere can i see why...  Code as follows:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels

Private Sub GoXSQ_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoXSQ.Click
If My.Settings.XSQ <> "" Then
        Dim XSQPService As New XSQ_Proxy.XsquareProxyService(New InstanceContext(Me))
        XSQPService.Url = "http://" + My.Settings.XSQ + ":9004/XSquareProxyService"
        Dim token As String = ""
        Try
            token = XSQPService.Authenticate(My.Settings.XSQUser, My.Settings.XSQPass)
        Catch ex As Exception
            SB.AppendText(Now() & " - Error communicating with XSQ API - " & ex.Message & " - " & ex.InnerException.ToString + Environment.NewLine)
        End Try
        If token <> "" And token > "000000" Then
            SB.AppendText(Now() & " - Token received: " & token + Environment.NewLine)
            '<!--- Insert XSQ process code here! ---!>
            Using scope As New OperationContextScope(XSQPService.InnerChannel)
                If Not OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("Authentication", "http://www.evs.tv/XMLSchema/Authentication/") = -1 Then
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.RemoveAt(OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("Authentication", "http://www.evs.tv/XMLSchema/Authentication/"))
                End If
                Dim header As MessageHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Authentication", "http://www.evs.tv/XMLSchema/Authentication/", token)
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header)
                Dim jobsrunning = XSQPService.GetMachines()
                For Each job In jobsrunning
                    SB.AppendText(job.Name)
                Next
            End Using
        Else
            SB.AppendText(Now() & " - XSQ API login failure - check username/password!" + Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The errors I am receiving are:

```
Dim XSQPService As New XSQ_Proxy.XsquareProxyService(New InstanceContext(Me))
```

Too many arguments to Public Sub New()

```
Using scope As New OperationContextScope(XSQPService.InnerChannel)
```

InnerChannel is not a member of...

I'm guessing the second is due to the first but I cannot find anything to identify why this phrase isn't working - its fully supported for .NET 4.0 which is my compile framework!

Any help would be appreciated

Paul